# Trouble with Update-Set-From syntax in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am trying to execute a simple SQL update-set-from statement in Oracle, which looks like the one below:

```
update
table1 t1
set
t1.col1=t2.col1
from
(select distinct t1.col1 from table1 t1 where t1.col2='xxx') as t2
where
t1.col1='yyy';
```

I haven't used `from` with `update-set` before, but this syntax looks okay to me. Yet it fails with this error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:
```

My desired result is for the inner select to return a single record, which then gets inserted/updated into table1's `col1`.

Also, should I be using a different alias than`t1` for `table1` in the inner select statement, considering that I have already used `t1` in the update statement?

Comment: You have mixed up something - there is no such option in Oracle database as `UPDATE ... FROM ...`, please study the [Oracle's syntax of UPDATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax should be

```
update table t1 set
  t1.col1 = (select distinct t2.col1 
             from table1 t2
             where t2.col2 = 'xxx')
where t1.col1 = 'yyy';
```

Note that `DISTINCT` doesn't necessarily mean that `SELECT` will return a single value; if it does not, you'll end up in `TOO-MANY-ROWS` error.